# How to Take Input String till End Of Line in C++ without the Use of getline

Tags: c++, string, input, character

I am writing a C++ Program
The input string for the same includes a string which contains alphanumeric char, symbols, whitespaces.
I need to take input till the end of line which signifies the end of input string

Tried using `do while` like below, but `while (value != '\n' || value != '\0');` is never getting satisfied, and even after pressing enter the while loop doesn't exit

```
do
{
    cin >> value;
    inputString.push(value);
} while (value != '\n' || value != '\0');
```

Example of Input String -

```
I am :IronnorI Ma, i
```

P.S. - I can't use `getline`, `string` library due to some coding constraints applicable in coding contests

Comment: What is `value`? Doesn't look like string.

Comment: please provide a [mcve] and the error message. "isn't working" does **not** describe your problem

Comment: @Ron - value is a char variable

Comment: @user463035818 **isn't working** here means that the condition
`while (value != '\n' || value != '\0');` is never getting satisfied, and even after pressing enter the `while` loop doesn't exit

Comment: this is what i was guessing, however you will get an answer more easily if no guessing is required. Just edit that last comment into your question

Comment: @user463035818 - thanks, I will edit and keep in mind since next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cin >> value;`, like all formatted input functions, skips all whitespace while looking for the next character to read. Whitespace includes `'\n'`, so it will never be read.

To read *all* characters, including the whitespace, you can use an unformatted input function like [`cin.get(value)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) instead.

Comment: i tried replacing `cin >> value` with `cin.get(value)`
But I am getting similar functionality

Comment: thanks for pointing out that `cin` ignores whitespaces
Would be helpful for me later :)

Comment: You also have to check the other answer. When actually reading `'\n'`, the while-condition becomes important too.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

The while condition can never be false and break the loop.

With value being equal to any other character than '\n' or '\0' it will obviously be true and the loop will continue.

But, assuming value is '\n'. The condition will evaluate to `while ('\n' != '\n' || '\n' != '\0')`, thus `while (false || true)`, thus `while (true)`.

Now assuming value is '\0': `while ('\0' != '\n' || '\0' != '\0')` is equal to `while (true || false)` is equal to `while (true)`.

What you need (as condition) is something like `while (! (value == '\n' || value == '\0'))` or (probably better) `while (value != '\n' && value != '\0')`.

Comment: i don't think that is the problem here
the problem is that `cin` ignores whitespaces as pointed by @Bo Persson below
So the check is never satisfied

Comment: It was *part of* the problem apparently. After all, you did change the operator in the while-condition from OR to AND, didn't you? ;-)

Comment: yeah it was also a part of the problem, but that would had been easier to figure out once I was able to include the whitespaces from the input. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Had to ignore the whitespace `'\n'` that was there during the first input
and then use `cin.get()` to get the whole line as a string

`cin >> noOfTestCases >> ws;`

```
do
{
  cin.get(value);
  inputString.push(value);
} while (value != '\n' && value != '\0');
```